# Google maps API getting drive time and road

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to achieve something like the following in the image 
[image]

but Actually I don't have any Idea if it's possible or how and where to start.
so if you can please lead me if it's possible or not, and how to achieve it or where to start
or if anyone knows a similar online working example it would be great
thanks in advance

Comment: I think you will need to use https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Comment: yes I've passed on that, but the thing is for example, when my user clicks on the Embedded Google map to calculate the distance between the 2 points I need to get them as locations to send them with the request , I'm stuck in here

Comment: what do you mean "embedded map"?

Comment: I mean embedded map?.. like the following, Google Map into an IFrame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer myself, yes it's possible thanks to [jfvanderwalt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491621/jfvanderwalt) for the useful link of [google Docs for Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) which led me to the working example of what I need and how to do it , here is my working [demo example](http://benseno.com.tr/demo/more/arama.html)
Javascript :

```
    <script>

var rendererOptions = {
  draggable: true
};
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

var australia = new google.maps.LatLng(41.171418,28.311553);

function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: australia
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directionsPanel'));

  google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
    computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.directions);
  });

  calcRoute();
}

function calcRoute() {

  var request = {
    origin: 'Istanbul, Turkey',
    destination: 'Ankara, Turkey',
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}

function computeTotalDistance(result) {
  var total = 0;
  var time= 0;
  var from=0;
  var to=0;
  var myroute = result.routes[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
    total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
    time +=myroute.legs[i].duration.text;
    from =myroute.legs[i].start_address;
    to =myroute.legs[i].end_address;


  }
  time = time.replace('hours','H');
  time = time.replace('mins','M');
  total = total / 1000.
  document.getElementById('from').innerHTML = from + '-'+to;
  document.getElementById('duration').innerHTML = time ;
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML =Math.round( total)+"KM" ;
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="map-canvas" style="margin-left:15px;float:left;width:930px; height:280px"></div>
<div style="float:left;padding-left:20px; padding-top:15px; width:100%; height: 80px;">
<div style="float:left;width: 50%;"><h3 id="from"></h3></div>
<div style="float:right;margin-right: 20px;width: 158px;text-align: right;">
<h3 id="duration"></h3>
</div>
<div style="float:right;width: 158px;text-align: right;">
```

Comment: can you provide a full demo example? I need exactly the same and your demo code does not work.